# proxy in front of mysql for redundancy removal

Tags: mysql, database, architecture, proxy

I'm trying to implement a proxy layer in front of MySQL server, that will catch redundant SQL queries and send them only once to the server. In other words, I have many clients (in PHP, Perl, on different web nodes) that talk to the MySQL and very often repeat the same `SELECT` queries. When traffic goes up MySQL, very often, goes down.

The question is - are you aware of any open source (or commercial) tool that can help? I tried [MySQL Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy), but looks like it can't help.

Comment: Usually people try to solve this caching the data returned by the sql on the application side. (Using memchached or similar applications to avoid having to re-query the database). I have never thought about it the other way around.

Comment: Question: When you say `very often repeat the same SELECT queries`, is the same query with the same parameters being requested, or is the same query with different parameters being requested?

Comment: It's the same query with the same parameters

Comment: Isn't the main idea of built-in query cache to take care of that ? I am only guessing but maybe the problem is just that you have too many queries for one server. So try some other approach which will enable you to distribute your queries across different server. Maybe the one @RolandoMySQLDBA suggested ?

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions:

1. MySQL Proxy
   This is a front end proxy from MySQL which does what you want as far as I know
2. vtocc
   From the vitess project, used in the YouTube mysql environment, also does a similar thing. Query consolidation: The ability to reuse the results of an in-flight query to any subsequent requests that were received while the query was still executing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) and [how it works](http://flavio.tordini.org/a-more-stable-mysql-with-haproxy/comment-page-1).

Here two additional suggestions

**SUGGESTION #1 Setup a Cluster**

If your data is all InnoDB, you should try [Percona XtraDB Cluster](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster/) and use HAProxy in conjunction with it. You can load balance across all server in the Cluster including the Write Master.

**SUGGESTION #2 Setup a Cluster via MySQL Replication to 1 or more DB Servers**

Use HAProxy to load balance your reads across the Read Slaves

If you are on a budget and your data is relatively small, [**setup multiple MySQL Instances on one server**](http://youtu.be/5uKBg9prA1A)

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't do what I'm looking for - identical SQL queries will still be able to reach MySQL at the same time

Comment: Both suggestions are great, but they don't solve the root cause of the problem - duplicated queries will reach the MySQL server. Extra servers/clusters will make the system bigger, but not smarter.